# What is a best practice when I receive notification data from an API into Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, rest, api

I receive notifications from an API when changes are made in an ERP.

The message I receive to the URL address (CallbackURL) is JSON type:

```
{
    "NotificationType": "Product Change",
    "ChangeType": "Update",
    "Trigger": "M_Product",
    "Value": "00087GH" 
}
```

I have multiple notification types and also change types. After that, I make some validations, connect the model and save the data in database.

Should I make all the logic in a controller? Which is a best practice for manipulating this kind of data?

Comment: I'd create an [event](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/events#defining-events), have the controller raise/dispatch it and have the logic within the [event listener](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/events#defining-listeners).

Comment: This is a very nice solution. Thank you! But is there any chance to dispatch the event when the notification hits the route? I mean, is there any solution for dispatching the event in the router?

Comment: The `event()` helper is generally available so you can do something like `event(new ProductChangeEvent($jsonArrayOfParameters))` or something like that. This can be called anywhere (e.g. in a route action callback). As an added bonus if your event implements the `ShouldQueue` interface then it can also be added to a queue for deferred handling .

Comment: Amazing. Thank you! You can add this as an answer to the question if you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an event that does this for you:

```
 class ProductChangeEvent {
      use SerializesModels;//Maybe needed
      public $parameters;
      public function __construct($parameters) {
           $this->parameters = $parameters;
      }
 }
```

Optionally this class can implement the `ShouldQueue` interface that allows it to be deferred.

You can handle that event via a listener:

```
class ProductChangeListener {

     public function handle(ProductChangeEvent $event) {
            switch ($event->parameters["NotificationType"]) {
                  //more cases?
                  case "Product Change": 
                  default:
                        $this->handleProductChange($event);
            }
     }

     protected function handleProductChange(ProductChangeEvent $event) {
           if ($event->parameters["ChangeType"] == "Update") {
               //Handle update product change
           }
     }
}
```

Obviously this is just an example. You can have the function split and cases according to your actual use cases.

You can then raise this event in the route handler:

```
Route::get("/eventListenerCallback", function (Request $req) {
      $parameters = json_decode($request->getContent(), true); //Is this right?
      event(new ProductChangeEvent($parameters));
});
```